# Asp.net core azure b2c cookie authentication on client

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, uwp, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web api written in asp.net core, and using Azure AD B2C for authentication. Everything works just fine in the browser: the endpoints with [Authorize] attribute require login, so the browser redirects me to the Azure login page, and after I'm logged in I got the answer from the api.

For the client I'm building a UWP app. I managed to get the Access Token using Microsoft.Identity.Client Nuget package, but I can't get send the request using the token. Everytime I'm trying I get an exception (I't thrown in the client code below):

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072F88): The HTTP
>   redirect request must be confirmed by the user at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpHandlerToFilter.d__4.MoveNext() --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__86.MoveNext()

If I remove the [Autherize] attribute from the endpoint, it works just fine.

My server side code:

Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdB2C(options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); })
        .AddCookie();
```

So I'm using Cookie authentication scheme. But from the client I can't properly attach the access token.

My client code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, uri);
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", ".AspNetCore.Cookies=" + token);
            //request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

The login work perfectly in UWP as well, but after it I can't do anything with the Authorized endpoints.

So how should I attach the access token to my http request to authorize properly using the given scheme?

Comment: The token you have is a Bearer token, not a cookie. You need to attach it as `Authorization: Bearer token-goes-here`, and configure and use JWT Bearer token authentication in your API, not cookie authentication.

Comment: Thank you, it helped solving my problem.